# Why the last element of the array is setting to '-1' automatically?

Tags: c, arrays, histogram

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0
#define maxword 15

main()
{
int j,i,state,c,nc_word;
nc_word = 0;
int count [maxword];
for(i=0;i<=maxword;i++)
    count[i]=0;
state = OUT;

while((c=getchar())!= EOF)
{
    if( c == ' '|| c == '\t'||c == '\n')
    {
       if (state == IN){
        ++count[nc_word];
        nc_word = 0;
       }
       state = OUT;

    }
    else
    {
        state = IN;
        ++nc_word;
    }
 }
for(i=13 ; i>=1 ; --i)
 {
    printf("\n%d",i);
   for(j=1;j<=count[i];j++){
        printf(" *");
   }
 }
 }
```

This program prints histogram of number of characters in a word. But it sets the last element of the array count[] to -1 (-1 is EOF value in my case).
For example, if there is one 14 character word in the input, count[14] should be 1, but its not working.. it always sets to -1.Why is it happening?

Comment: The valid indexes in `count` are `0 to maxword-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `<` instead of `<=` in `for(i=0;i<=maxword;i++)`.
You are trying to access memory space that doesn't belong to your array.

Comment: Wow Boom!... it worked. I accidentally wrote <= instead of <. Thanx pal.

Answer (score 1):

> check your index once, it's printing garbage values. 
>   and in what space sir, your this statement exist ? i don't understand

```
++count[nc_word];
```

Comment: It was not concisely printing garbage... it was printing -1 which is EOF value...Which array uses to detect end of elements.. anyways .. thanx ..and i still don't know what you trying to say about the "++count[nc_word];" statement .